# How to change media url in django while serving media files using apache2?

Tags: django, django-media

I have a website in production that serves media files properly.

Media Setting in `settings.py` file :

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I have created a media folder inside my project where my all media are being stored. Due to the media URL it severs media files as `https://domain_name/media/file_name`.

I want to serve my media files as `https://domain_name/images/file_name`.

I try to change the MEDIA_URL setting in `settings.py` file, but it shows `404` error for the images.

Updated `settings.py` file

```
MEDIA_URL = 'images/'    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I am using apache2 as a webserver. Apache file setting:

```
Alias /static /path_to_the_project/static
  <Directory /path_to_the_project/static>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>


Alias /media /path_to_the_project/media
        <Directory /path_to_the_project/media>
               Require all granted
        </Directory>

  Alias /media /path_to_the_project/images
        <Directory /path_to_the_project/images>
               Require all granted
        </Directory>

<Directory /path_to_the_project/clorrr_tailors>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
      </Directory>
```

And In template am accessing the images as :

```
<img src="{{object.image.url}}">
```

Comment: Are your media files being served by a webserver (Nginx, Apache, etc.) and if so can you show the config? Can you also show how you are referencing the file urls in your template/view?

Comment: You need to change your Apache config to map `/images` to your media folder

Comment: **I have tried that way also @Iain Shelvington**
My all media files are inside the media folder. And I just want to change the media_url. 
In my local server when I changed the setting MEDIA_URL  = 'images/', it working fine. But only in production it not showing proper images.

Comment: In production when changing the media url you also need to change the apache config to serve the media directory from that same url. You need to change both the Django setting and Apache directory alias. It works locally because Django serves media files directly when running the dev server.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I have uploaded the full apache2 configuration. Check whether I need to change anything ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248095/discussion-between-manoj-kamble-and-iain-shelvington).

Comment: `I need to change` - of course. Your aliases are still mapping `media` url to folders instead of `images` url.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the Absolute file path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

`MEDIA_URL` on the other hand is a placeholder for the url a client should hit to access your media.

So in your case `MEDIA_URL` is `'images/'` that means url will be pointed to images to access the data in `MEDIA_ROOT` ie the directory `media` in your BASE Directory

Comment: I tried to change the `MEDIA_URL = 'images/' it shows 404 for the images.